# Angular: Binding Component Input to Property of Value from Observable

Tags: angular, data-binding, binding, observable

In Angular 7, when the property of a value emitted by an `Observable` is bound to the input of a child component, is it expected that the input value gets updated (and `ngOnChanges` invoked) even when the bound property has not changed?

Given the following observable that simply emits a new object with identical properties every second:

```
const source$ = interval(1000).pipe(map(() => ({
  prop: 'something'
})));
this.obs$ = source$;
```

Then bind a property of the emitted value to a child component:

```
<test-comp [something]="(obs$ | async)?.prop"></test-comp>
```

What I observe is that the 'something' setter and `ngOnChanges` of `test-comp` get invoked.

Also, comparing current and previous values are checked in `ngOnChanges` shows they are identify equal:

```
if(changes['something'].currentValue === changes['something'].previousValue) {
  console.log('They are equal');
}
```

Using a separate observable that simply maps the property from the source observable like so:

```
this.obs2$ = source$.pipe(map(v => v.prop));

<test-comp [something]="(obs$ | async)"></test-comp>
```

Works as I had expected, with the 'something' value not being set and `ngOnChanges` not being called.

Here is a Stackblitz sample that shows the behaviour in question:

- Editor URL: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wch28k
- App URL: https://angular-wch28k.stackblitz.io

Using Angular 7.2.1

Perhaps I've just got it completely wrong, but the behaviour seems inconsistent

Comment: Why you using setter on your `TestComponent` it doesn't need to handle the change detection since you are using `async` pipe? Simply `@Input() val: string;` is all you need, any changes on that observable will push that change.

Comment: @penleychan The setter is just to make it very clear that the input value is being set, even though the value has not changed.  I think you have misunderstood the question, as I am not having issue getting changes from the observable to be pushed, it's quite the opposite.