# Angular Component Observable binding time

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have seen a similar question to this elsewhere, but without answer [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56569610/angular-binding-component-input-to-property-of-value-from-observable).

I have a service that is looking at local storage for a value. If it is there, it is setting that as the next value on the `Subject`, else it will make an http call.

I know the below is a contrived example, but I tried to come up with a MVP.

`test.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/internal/Subject';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class TestService {
  private testSubject: Subject<{ name: string }> = new Subject();
  testObservable$ = this.testSubject.asObservable();

  constructor() {
    var cat = localStorage.getItem('myCat');
    console.log(cat);
    this.testSubject.next({ name: cat });
  }

  update() {
    localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');
    this.testSubject.next({ name: 'not Tom' });
  }
}
```

Then in the component, I'm assigning the observable from above directly to a property on the model and exposing it to the template using the `async` pipe.

`app.component.ts`

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from './test.service';
import { map } from 'rxjs/internal/operators/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <p>
    Hello {{test$ | async}}!
  </p>

  <button (click)="onClick()">Click me!</button>`,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AppComponent {
  test$ = this.testService
              .testObservable$
              .pipe(
                map(a => a.name)
              );

  constructor(private testService: TestService) {
  }

  onClick() {
    this.testService.update();
  }
}
```

When my view renders, it isn't showing the name Tom, even after I have clicked the button the first time(to put the value in local storage) and reload the page(you can see that Tom is getting set as next value in the console).

Clicking the button though provides another 'next' value and then the UI does update properly. Seeing all of this, it would seem as though the observable is being subscribed to after the first value is being passed to the subject, so the UI isn't getting that initial value. I have tried numerous different things all to no avail. I have tried using a `BehaviorSubject` instead. Also tried using `shareReplay` and other operators. I've also tried setting up the observable in the `ngAfterViewInit` method. Still with no luck. If the data is in local storage, I wouldn't think that the user should have to take some action to view it immediately, but I can't seem to find the proper way of getting this to work.

How can I setup this observable properly so that it will get the information from local storage and place it into the view without the user needing to take some action?

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ajdqkm) with the code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56818773/how-to-build-a-service-that-gets-values-async-but-also-perfoms-tasks-on-that-dat/56818828#56818828

Comment: Using `this.testSubject.next` in the constructor is fine, but nobody is listening at that time. So you might want to use `ReplaySubject` or `BehaviorSubject` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a standard subscription timing issue... async pipe is subscribing after the signal is emitted... make it a behaviorsubject or replaysubject instead to broadcast last subject value to new subscribers.

```
private testSubject: ReplaySubject<{ name: string }> = new ReplaySubject(1);
```

Comment: For the StackBlitz example this seems to work, so I'll mark it as the answer. I'm trying to use this in a Chrome extension though and there, no matter what I try, `Subject`, `BehaviorSubject`, `ReplaySubject`, it still isn't working. Any thoughts?